# Timezone offset not working in angular js date expression

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I have `2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452` as ISO string from backend server.
My timezone is +0530 GMT i.e Offset is +530 (ahead of GMT).

When i use angular date expression like this

`{{'2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452'| date:'medium':'+530'}}`

**I expected output to be = Oct 21, 2016 7:17:02 PM 
but it prints 
Oct 21, 2016 1:47:02 PM instead.**

I am confused for what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: `{{'2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452'| date:'medium'}}`

Comment: I tried using this but it still print out Oct 21, 2016 1:47:02 PM . It wont take timezone from my browser. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself !
The easiest way that i figured out ! Make a custom filter

```
   app.filter('IST', function($filter){
        return function(val){
            var date = new Date(val);
            return $filter(date, 'medium');
        }
    })
```

Then use filter in expression like this -

```
{{'2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452'| IST}}
```

Custom filter will automatically convert ISO format string to Date object (browser timezone will automatically take care of timezone conversion.)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
var d = new Date('2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452');
console.log(d)
```

Comment: I know this but this would be a hack. I want it to give correct output only by expression itself !

Comment: then try this
{{ "2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452" | date : 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss' : '+1100' }}

Comment: Didn't worked. Check this [http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11032/] @ali-sadiq

Answer (score 0):

Date pipe transforms the date string you are passing (`'2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452'`) to a Date object and then applies the time zone offset.

¿Whats the problem? When transforming `'2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452'` to a Date, it supposes that the date is in your local time, so the final calculation is wrong. For example, I am in +0200 so the transformation will be:

- `2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452` -> `2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452+0200` (Date object)
- `2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452+0200` -> `2016-10-21T18:17:02.922452+0530` (date changes with offset difference 0530-0200)

If your backend date is always in GMT timezone, just add `Z` to your date string: `2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452Z`. This way, when creating the Date it will understand that the initial timezone is +0000

Solution:

```html
{{'2016-10-21T13:47:02.922452Z' | date:'medium':'+0530'}}
```